# Boto3 List object adds extra string after delimiter

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to get all the folders located in my s3 bucket using boto3 list_objects. I'm using '/' as the Delimiter. When I retrieve the keys from content it adds an extra string "$folder$" to the folder name

Tried using $ in the delimiter but it only takes in one string which is matched with the output.

```py
s3 = session.client("s3")
all_info = s3.list_objects(Bucket = bucket_name,Delimiter= '/')
for content in all_info.get('Contents', []):
    print(content.get('Key'))
```

Output:

```
Folder_1_name$folder$
Folder_2_name$floder$
Folder_3_name$folder$
Folder_4_name$floder$
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you don't put the `Delimiter='/'` in the query?

Comment: Yes! It still happens if I remove the delimiter

Comment: And you're sure that the key names actually don't contain those? It doesn't show up in the console? Or using the CLI?

Comment: It doesn't show up in s3 console

Comment: Are you running EMR using those buckets? Apparently it could be due to MapReduce: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/

Comment: ahh that makes sense!